# How can I execute a method of a class that has been uploaded?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

The goal is to implement a web application that can execute methods of `.class` files that has been uploaded. The uploaded class file is available as a `byte[]`. The public class in this `.class` file implements a specific interface.
After the upload, I'd like to call a method (interface implementation).

Is there a way to do so in a running java application? If yes, how?

*Btw. I'm aware of the security risks.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard:

1. Create your own classloader (not hard, see below).
2. Load the class using [`ClassLoader#defineClass(String, byte[], int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).
3. Check it implements your interface (`YourInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(loadedClass);`).
4. Use java reflection/introspection on the `Class<?>` you just got on step 1. (e.g. `YourInterface obj = (YourInterface)loadedClass.newInstance();`).
5. Call the method: `obj.shinyMethod();`

Re creating your own classloader: Here's a simple one that just delegates to the system class loader:

```
class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public MyClassLoader() {
        super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    }

    // Our custom public function for loading from a byte array,
    // this is here just because defineClass is final, so we
    // can't just make it public. Name can be anything you want.
    public Class<?> loadClassFromByteArray(byte[] data)
    throws ClassFormatError {
        return this.defineClass(null, data, 0, data.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that sounds promising! But `defineClass`is protected.. do I need to subclass ClassLoader (which I'm a bit afraid of)? Or is there another way?

Comment: Standard classloaders are designed to protect themselves against people injecting random stuff (you've mentioned how unsafe that could be), so yes, you'll need your own ClassLoader implementation (although it could extend an existing one) to achieve this.

Comment: @Mulmoth: I've added an example of how to create your own classloader that just defers to the system class loader.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you T.J. for adding the `super(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())` thing.